# Flipping Road-Lines based on direction of apparently parallel DrainageLines derived using DEM

Tags: arcgis-desktop, dem

I have 2 FeatureClasses one is road lines (Red coloured as shown in the attached image) with random digitized direction and another is drainage lines (Blue Lines) derived using Raster DEM with correct direction. Mostly, the DrainageLines fc has lines apparently parallel to all road lines and also lateral sub drainlines.

[image: DrainageLines and Road Lines]

I need to correct the direction of road lines based on the direction of seemingly parallel lines in Drainageline FeatureClass. I may just need to flip road lines if their bearing is opposite to parallel DrainageLines only (but should not consider other than parallel lines) or based on some other logic. Its difficult to flip them manually as they are in thousands.

Is there a method or any tools/procedure to perform this job on ArcGIS Desktop?

Comment: Do you have access to the DEM?

Comment: Yes, I have SRTM 1 arc-sec DEM and those drainageLines are derived using the DEM only by burning road lines to DEM.

Comment: Find dangles in roads. Find nearest stream node. Trace stream network from them. Remove other streams. Travel distance is your measure. Flip road segments, where it is greater for end point of segment compared to start point.